# Codespace/Cloud Workstation Isolated Testing

Tags: go, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

Preface: We do not currently have a way of spinning up an environment automatically. We also do not have a mesh on K8s cluster running yet (in the works)

Currently the architecture of our environment is multi-tiered. We have hundreds of microservices and some of those microservices use other microservices while it's running. I want to provide our developers a way of testing their changes in an integrated fashion, but without deploying in a way that would expose their unfinished changes and break items for other users.

We have google cloud workstation deployed as a solution and while they're developing their services, they're able to test just the microservice in the workstation, but when they get to a point of wanting to see the microservice work within the context of the whole environment, they currently deploy to our shared dev environment which sometimes breaks things for other developers. Is there a solution that would allow us to inject our IDE debugger so that when you submit a request to the frontend, it knows to send the corresponding backend requests to your IDE vs the deployed pod.

Stack:
React Frontend
Go Backend deployed on K8s.
Google Cloud Platform

All frontend and backend code is developed on Google Cloud Workstations

I looked into skaffold, but based on documentation that doesn't look to achieve what I'm looking for.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.